# How do I display (by default) milliseconds in TOAD for MySql?

Tags: mysql, toad

I have version 5.6.24 MySql.

When I use command line:

```
 "select * from mytable;"
```

with cygwin MySql I can see the milliseconds properly formatted.

However, the same command in TOAD, displays Datetime only down to seconds.

How can I get TOAD to act correctly like MySql command?

Comment: `View->Options->Data Grids->Data` Set Date Format as you want

Comment: That forces SAME pattern on all DATETIME columns. I have mix of DATETIME and DATETIME(3). MySql command line applies different appropriate patterns to each.

Comment: This is only matter of presentation the tool you use, if you want specific formatting use `DATE_FORMAT`: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4a2ad/5/0